# Permissions to enable download of Word document into PDF

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, pdf, word-automation, word-pdf

SharePoint Online.  When a user clicks on a Word document in SharePoint, I would like the automatic behavior to do 2 things:

1. convert the document to PDF
2. download the PDF to the user's computer

Does anyone know how this can be done?  Is it possible to do through permissions?

**UPDATE 7/18/2017: I understand this functionality to be Word Automation and it isn't available in SharePoint Online (scroll down to bottom of page):
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-content-service-description.aspx

Comment: As this is not available out-of-the-box, you may want to search the SharePoint App store for 'pdf converter' (I wonder which product will show in the results :-) - https://store.office.com/en-001/appshome.aspx?productgroup=sharepoint

Answer (score 5):

**First**, what you have asked is not related to the SharePoint Permission.

**Second**, unfortunately, the PDF auto conversion is not available in SharePoint.

---

**The available options that may satisfy a few of your requirements are:**

- From the beginning, you should upload your document as a PDF file.
- Or you can open your word document first in the browser then save it as PDF on your computer.

> By the way, The required permission to download a document is at least
>   **Read** permission, you can't download a document using **View Only** permission.